# Can't connect Android application to MySQL database using WAMP as local server

Tags: php, android, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to create a simple login to my Android application that compares the input from the user to data from a database following these tutorials:

- http://androidcss.com/android/test-android-app-php-localhost-wamp/
- http://androidcss.com/android/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial/

I'm using WAMP as a local server just to test if I can make the connection. 
I have two PHP-files called *config.inc.php* and *login.inc.php* placed in the following directory: *C:\wamp64\www\DUFT* and they look like this:

config.inc.php

```
<?php $servername = "localhost:80"; 
  $username = "root";
  $password = "root";
  $dbname = "duft";

  try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    die("OOPs something went wrong");
}

?>
```

login.inc.php

```
<?php

 include 'config.inc.php';

 // Check whether username or password is set from android  
 if(isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password']))
 {
      // Innitialize Variable
      $result='';
      $username = $_POST['username'];
      $password = $_POST['password'];

      // Query database for row exist or not
      $sql = 'SELECT * FROM tbl_login WHERE  email = :username AND adgangskode = :password';
      $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
      $stmt->execute();
      if($stmt->rowCount())
      {
         $result="true";    
      }  
      elseif(!$stmt->rowCount())
      {
            $result="false";
      }

      // send result back to android
      echo $result;
}?>
```

Then I have my LoginActivity class where I'm using AsyncTask to make the connection to the database in the background. In the onPostExecute() method I'm trying to start a new activity if the user input matches what is in the database. But I keep getting this error from the PHP-files:

> ( ! ) Warning:
>   PDO::__construct(): MySQL server has gone away in
>   C:\wamp64\www\DUFT\login.inc.php on line *10*Call Stack#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation10.0042244400{main}(  )...\login.inc.php**:**020.0043245592http://www.php.net/PDO.construct' target='_new'>__construct(
>   )...\login.inc.php**:**10( ! ) Warning:
>   PDO::__construct(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=9636 in
>   C:\wamp64\www\DUFT\login.inc.php on line *10*Call Stack#TimeMemoryFunctionLocation10.0042244400{main}(  )...\login.inc.php**:**020.0043245592http://www.php.net/PDO.construct' target='_new'>__construct(
>   )...\login.inc.php**:**10OOPs
>   something went wrong

This is what my logcat says:

[image: Logcat]

My LoginActivity Java class looks like this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

//NYT
// CONNECTION_TIMEOUT and READ_TIMEOUT are in milliseconds

public static final int CONNECTION_TIMEOUT=2000000000;
public static final int READ_TIMEOUT=2000000000;
private EditText etEmail;
private EditText etPassword;
//NYT

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    //NYT
    // Get Reference to variables
    etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.eMail);
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    //NYT


    TextView klikHer = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.klikHer);
    klikHer.setPaintFlags(klikHer.getPaintFlags() | Paint.UNDERLINE_TEXT_FLAG);

    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signIn);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuScreen.class);
            //startActivity(intent);

            //NYT
            // Get text from email and passord field
            final String email = etEmail.getText().toString();
            final String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

            // Initialize  AsyncLogin() class with email and password
            new AsyncLogin().execute(email, password);
            //NYT
        }
    });
}


private class AsyncLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    ProgressDialog pdLoading = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    HttpURLConnection conn;
    URL url = null;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        //this method will be running on UI thread
        pdLoading.setMessage("\tLoading...");
        pdLoading.setCancelable(false);
        pdLoading.show();

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {

            // Enter URL address where your php file resides
            url = new URL("http://192.168.87.100/DUFT/login.inc.php");

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }
        try {
            // Setup HttpURLConnection class to send and receive data from php and mysql
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            //conn.setReadTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT);
            //conn.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // setDoInput and setDoOutput method depict handling of both send and receive
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            // Append parameters to URL
            Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder()
                    .appendQueryParameter("username", params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter("password", params[1]);
            String query = builder.build().getEncodedQuery();

            // Open connection for sending data
            OutputStream os = conn.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                    new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
            writer.write(query);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
            os.close();
            conn.connect();

        } catch (IOException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        }

        try {

            int response_code = conn.getResponseCode();

            // Check if successful connection made
            if (response_code == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {

                // Read data sent from server
                InputStream input = conn.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));
                StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                String line;

                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    result.append(line);
                }

                // Pass data to onPostExecute method
                return (result.toString());

            } else {

                return ("unsuccessful");
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "exception";
        } finally {
            conn.disconnect();
        }


    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        //this method will be running on UI thread

        pdLoading.dismiss();

        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("true")) {
            /* Here launching another activity when login successful. If you persist login state
            use sharedPreferences of Android. and logout button to clear sharedPreferences.
             */

            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MenuScreen.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            LoginActivity.this.finish();

        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {

            // If username and password does not match display a error message
            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Invalid email or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).Show();


        } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("exception") || result.equalsIgnoreCase("unsuccessful")) {

            //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "OOPs! Something went wrong. Connection Problem.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).Show();

        }
    }
}}
```

I have followed all the steps in the tutorials, and I'm able to access the local server with my phone by entering the IPv4 address into my mobile browser. This must mean that I'm also able to access a database on this local server, right?

Comment: did allow connections at your httpd config file

Comment: try by removing host port :80 in config.php..

Comment: @OussemaAroua can you tell me more specific how to allow connections?

Comment: update catch block in config.php using ** die("Failed to connect to the database: " . $ex->getMessage()); **

Comment: @Omi I changed the catch block and it gave me this message now: Failed to connect to the database: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

Comment: by adding `Allow from all` at your httpd.conf file

Comment: Try to access this url in Postman and check response

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution! The problem was in this line of code

```
php $servername = "localhost:80";
```

Here I define the port for Apache instead of MySQL which is 3307. So I just changed it to the right port which is 3307 :)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: 1) Leave the port number `:3307` off and it will take the default set in the php.ini 2) MySQL normally runs on port 3306

Comment: Port 3307 is used in WAMPServer 3.0.7 and above for MariaDB